# How to create a searchable dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have some drop-down lists that the user can use as a filter to manipulate what they see in the grid view. To stop the drop-down list getting too long, I would like the user to be able to search for what they need in it rather than scrolling.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.searchabledropdown-1.0.8.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("ddlBoxNo").searchable({
      maxListSize: 200,
      maxMultiMatch: 300,
      exactMatch: false,
      wildcards: true,
      ignoreCase: true,
      latency: 200,
      warnMultiMatch: 'top {0} matches ...',
      warnNoMatch: 'no matches ...',
      zIndex: 'auto'
    });
  });
```

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBoxNo" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" style="width: 220px; max-width: 220px">
  <asp:ListItem Text="All Box Numbers" Value="0"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I expected to be able to search for a record but actually the drop-down list isn't searchable/editable at all.

Comment: You have two problems. 1) the selector is missing a class or id prefix. 2) You're using a `runat="server" attribute on the element, so it's `id` will change dynamically at runtime. You need to use the `ClientId` property to select it. Also, the plugin you're using seems very limited. I'd suggest using Select2 as it's much more full featured

Comment: I would suggest using Combo boxes for this issue

Comment: I will have a look at Select2 now.

I am using drop-down lists because the data in them is from my database tables.